# Setting Up Multiple Google Analytics Accounts

Tags: google-analytics

I posted this on Google's help forums, but I still haven't gotten a response, so I thought I'd try it here;

I work for a web development company with 200+ active clients. We are in the process of setting up Google Analytics tracking for each of their websites. We have already created a Google account for each of our clients, and we are attempting to manually sign each one up for GA. We haven't gotten very far in creating new GA accounts, after creating a few accounts, we are required to use text-message verification to create the accounts, and after a few more, we are unable to create any new accounts at all.

We are following the recommendation of Google's Help Article found here:
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55601

We are a legitimate business trying to set up analytics for legitimate customers. At this point we can't create a single new GA account, but we still have 182 clients that we have promised to set up with GA, plus any new customers, all of which we intend to set up with GA. We've clearly been flagged as a robot by Google's system, which is totally understandable given the volume of accounts we are creating, but we are not using any robots, we have a person sitting at a computer manually entering all of the information for each of our clients.

Does anyone have any ideas or a solution?

Comment: Have you tried contacting google?

Comment: And by contact I mean talk to an actual GA Account Manager, not post on their public help forum.

Comment: I'd love to, but that kind of contact information isn't exactly easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging in as a different client each time in order to open the new account?

If so, try logging in as yourself and creating each new accounts in your profile. Once created, add your client as a user (report or admin level).